# Ruby on Rails ActiveAdmin + TinyMCE error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, tinymce-rails

I was following the guide I found online to put **ActiveAdmin** and **TinyMCE** together into use, but I encountered a strange error which I was not able to search up the solution for it.

One part of it was to add in this line to **config/initializers/active_admin.rb**:

**config.register_javascript 'tinymce.js'**

However, when I try to run the app, an error says:

**/Users/RageBill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5ebf476abd92/lib/active_admin/application.rb:49:in `method_missing': undefined method`register_javascript' for # (NoMethodError)**

Any thoughts on how can I resolve this problem? Thank you very much :)

(P.S. my rails version is 5.1.3 if that would be helpful.)

Comment: You are using ActiveAdmin master?  Try branch: '1-1-stabe'

Answer (score 0):

I found:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/340

This sholud work:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  config.register_stylesheet "//cdn.foo.net/example.css"

  config.register_javascript "//cdn.foo.net/example.js"

 # ...
end
```